# No Autolayout needed when we put two splashes of 640 x 960 and 640 x 1136 dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have today experienced something weird. Here's what I did. I just created a new project and added a new launch set in image.xcassets.
I am using Xcode 6.4

There I only used two splashes

1. **640 X 960**
2. **640 X 1136**

[image]

Then I just made a view with two text fields and label in the middle. I didn't put any constraint and built my UI on **any x any** size class dimension and 4 inch view

The preview which I saw is wrong as I have not set any constraints

[image]

But When I ran the app in various devices and simulators (4s 5s 6 6plus) The labels and textfields were exactly in the center as they are shown in the 4inch or 3.5 inch figure.

Later I also added the **750x1334** launch image in my image.xcassets and that made the difference. The preview which I posted is now behaving exactly the same in every device. But again I removed this splash  **750x1334** and everything again seems to be fixed without any single constraint. Has anyone tried that thing. What can be the problem and a solution for that or this is a bug in xcode?

Comment: A comment regarding your launch image: Apple recommends to not put text in there, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html). Just so you know :) Most apps conform to this.

Comment: @fabian789 What are you talking about. Where is the text in my launch image? The preview is my login screen and in my launch image i dont have any text.. just a logo

Comment: Ah I see. Excuse my confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide splash for 6 and 6+ then your app will run in `Scale Mode`

What it does?
Scale mode scales your 4 inch screen in 4.7 and 5 inch screen.

You can read [Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips) section of this article for more. This was done so that the apps on the apps store (before the launch of 6 & 6+) should run on newer devices without updating the apps.

Comment: ok so, the problems of making a label scale can be solved by this? Because label never scale whenever we put any constraint. We have to manage it  by check of various devices. In this case we also dont need a autolayout thing?

Comment: I don't get you what you are asking specifically, but yes you have to support only 3.5 and 4 inch screen in this case. Yes you can ignore autolayout in this case

Comment: Lets say a UILabel is placed somewhere in center in 4s. I want this label to be scaled in 5s 6 and 6 plus according to screen size. Is it possible from autolayout as UILabel is intrinsic type

Comment: Lets say a UILabel is placed somewhere in center in 4s. I want this label to be scaled in 5s 6 and 6 plus according to screen size. Is it possible from autolayout as UILabel is intrinsic type. Even aspect ratio doesn't work on UILabel and only works on UIview or imageviews.

Comment: Whatever happens to label in 4s, it will be same in 5/6/6+. Width wise there won't be any effect. But when app runs on iPhone5 the height will increase thus you might be considering the constraint for iPhone5 not for iPhone6 or 6+

Comment: Make sure that apps works for 4s and 5, the scale mode just scales the app.

Comment: Problem is that suppose we have size classes and diff font sizes for iphone n ipad. I want something with various iPhones too so that i case of iphone 6 the font size is increased just like it does in uiview when we set aspect ratio. And yes, there should not be any kinda check of iphone in code

Comment: The size classes for iphone6 won't be consider in case of scale mode. Scale mode just scales the iphone5 app into iphone6 and 6+, that's it

Comment: I was talking without scaled mode. Is there a way without writing any code to achieve this. Suppose label is 12 in iphone 5. It should become 13 in 6 and 14 in 6+. Any idea. But no code please.

Comment: May be, just upload it and check. As long as you can upload the binary successfully it is acceptable.